# Replacing NewLine Character with an Empty String

Tags: excel, vb.net, csv

I want to add a new column with blank fields in my existing CSV data.

My current code is like this:

```
  Dim data As IEnumerable(Of String) =
                                File.ReadLines(filename,Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")).
                                Select(Function(line, index)
                                           If index = 0 Then
                                               Return "new_column," & line
                                           Else
                                               Return "," & line
                                           End If
                                       End Function)

                               File.WriteAllLines(savePath, data)
```

The problem is that "new_column" is being added on the line breaks. So, what I did is to open the CSV file in Excel and used the following steps:

1. `Ctrl + H` to open up the `Find and Replace` dialog box.
2. On the `Find What` text box, I used `Ctrl + J` to enter a line break character. I followed the instructions [here](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2013/05/28/find-and-replace-line-breaks-in-excel/)

I tried using `ReadAllText` but the rows are not in the correct order after writing it.

Is there an alternate same way to what I am doing with Excel in VB.NET?

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to add that I am trying to replace `Environment.NewLine` on the `line` string with an empty character. But to no avail. I tried it with `ReadAllText` and replacing the `Environment.NewLine` but to no avail as well. This also destroyed the rows.

Comment: You can try to use `vbCrLF` instead of `Environment.NewLine`. But remember, not every OS uses this for a line break.

Comment: *`new_column` is being added on the line breaks* what does this mean?. The code you're using will create a new `.CSV` file correctly. `File.ReadLines()` strips the line breaks and `WriteAllLines()` puts them back. (A problem here might be that you're using `iso-8859-1` to read, but the output file is UTF-8 encoded). Do you mean, you want to add just a line feed (char `10`), instead of carriage return + line feed (char `13` + char `10`)? If so, you could change this: `Return "new_column," & line & vbLf` (or `ChrW(10)`). And use  `StreamWriter.WriteLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

With a CSV file saved from Excel, if there is a line break in a cell then the cell value will be surrounded with double-quotes and the line break is represented by a Chr(10).

For example,

[image]

saved as a CSV file and opened in a hex editor gives (note: 10 decimal = 0A hexadecimal)

```
43 6F 6C 20 41 2C 43 6F 6C 20 42 2C 22 4C 69 6E Col A,Col B,"Lin
65 0A 62 72 65 61 6B 22 2C 43 6F 6C 20 44 0D 0A e·break",Col D··
```

So you need something which will regard a line break inside a double-quoted string as not being a new line.

The [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.7.2) can be configured to do that by setting the .HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes property to True.

For example, with the above data,

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim src = "C:\temp\Book1.csv"
        Dim dest = "C:\temp\newColumn.csv"

        Using tfp As New TextFieldParser(src)
            tfp.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
            tfp.Delimiters = {","}
            Dim re As New Regex("[,\n]")

            Using sw As New StreamWriter(dest, False, Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"))
                While Not tfp.EndOfData
                    Dim thisLine = tfp.ReadFields()
                    sw.WriteLine("new_column," & String.Join(",", thisLine.Select(Function(p) If(re.IsMatch(p), Chr(34) & p & Chr(34), p))))
                End While
            End Using

        End Using

    End Sub

End Module
```

generates

```
6E 65 77 5F 63 6F 6C 75 6D 6E 2C 43 6F 6C 20 41 new_column,Col A
2C 43 6F 6C 20 42 2C 22 4C 69 6E 65 0A 62 72 65 ,Col B,"Line·bre
61 6B 22 2C 43 6F 6C 20 44 0D 0A                ak",Col D··
```

Which can be opened in Excel to give:

[image]

<strike>You may need to make it more robust than putting double-quotes around only entries with a Chr(10), for example entries with a comma in need the delimiters too.</strike>

I wrote it to also delimit fields with commas, although that isn't shown in the example data.

Of course, once you have the individual entries from a line in the array `thisLine`, you could replace the Chr(10) with a space, if desired.